# Is Herobrine real?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I been wondering since I first heard about Herobrine," Is Herobrine Real?","Is Herobrine really deleted?" Post your answers below please. Thanks. : )

Comment: No, he was removed in the latest update.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!

Answer (score 4):

No, he is made up.

Mire info on the [WIKI](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Herobrine)

> Herobrine is not in Minecraft.
>
> There are no references to him at all in the source code, and there is no code to allow for any entity to act like Herobrine. There is no level terrain code to generate redstone torches, 2x2 tunnels or elaborate dungeons with traps.
>
> There is no possible way Herobrine can ever exist in any unmodded clients or servers. Any claims that he is in Minecraft are completely false. Any appearances he may have are caused by mods being installed.
>
> The Minecraft Wiki and Forums do not partake in any viral Herobrine hoax. Any deletion of Herobrine-related comments or stories are purely because Herobrine does not exist, and the stories are either fictional, with an intent to mislead others, or the result of users playing mods installed on their game without their knowledge.

Missed opportunity for a "Halloween" update, if you ask me.

Comment: Oh,I see,I just didn't understand at first.